# iphone app images disappear on update

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I have a photo location app which allows the users to take a photo of the location when saving.  Up until IOS8 whenever an update was applied all previously entered info was saved, including the image taken.

Since IOS8, all info is retained but the images no longer show, this causes the App to crash when trying to share locations via Facebook, Twitter etc because it is expecting an image.

Is there anything specific i should be looking for relating to behaviour since the new OS?

Comment: You mean you are not getting current location of the user?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the issue, like crash logs, code on how the images are saved and retrieved. Because you current question is lacking a bit to tell what is going on.

Comment: The current location stopped working as well because of IOS8 @Bhumit but i have fixed this now and it is working again.

Comment: It's just the images that don't show when updating.

Comment: Hej, did you find out a solution for this? I'm seeing the same thing, using phonegap.